# Bit selection in perl

Tags: perl

How can we bit select the variables in perl code?

I am new to perl and I have a scenario where I need to extract a particular format from a file and give input to a another module for analysis.

Currently I have extracted the required pattern which is in 16-bit Hexadecimal. 
Now from this *16bits* hexadecimal format ,I want only *LSB 10bits*. 
Kindly refer the below example(This is a sample code where I have used only 1 line of my requirement)

```
use strict;
my $string = "HDR 0c0d PlD 1000 GAP 412";
$string =~ s/.*HDR\s(\S+).*/$1/g;
print "$string\n";
my $hex = hex($string);
print "$hex";
```

The output in `$hex` is 3095 which is *16bit* `16’b0011000010000101` now I need to extract only the LSB *10bits*(`0010000101`), Please let me know some easy way to do this .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use bit mask to select bits which you need. To select right 10 bit you can use:

```perl
my $x = 0xfff0;
print $x & 0x3ff;
```

output is

> 1008

which is decimal number of ten bits of number 0xfff0

Comment: Thank you @oklas , your logic helps !

Comment: Welcome! Do not forget mark ansewer solved. And vote answers which you like to make it visible for others. (You will be enable to make vote after some votes to your q/a will be accumullated)